# CSS for moving the image to center of a div using background-position

Tags: html, css

```
<div class="divOverlay">
  <div class="div-overlay-content" >
    <div class="pointer" ></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have the following setup where I have a div with a background image and another pointer that always stays in the center. I want to move the background image dynamically to different positions. I am doing that by adjusting the  properties

```
background-position: 0% 0%;
```

So if I set it to 50% 50%, then the center of the image is aligned with the pointer in the center. which is fine. But I have to tackle the corner scenarios .for eg:- if the value is 0% 0%, then I should have the top left corner of the image aligned to the center (with white background space where there is no image)

How to achieve this just by using CSS (without modifying the image to add the extra white spaces)?

Here is the link to jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mkd914gf/21/

Here is the CSS

```
.divOverlay {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
 }

.div-overlay-content{
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   background-image: url(https://topdrawer.aamt.edu.au/var/aamt/storage/images/media/tdt/patterns/p_gt_t3_e1_a1_fig1/278788-1-eng-AU/P_GT_T3_E1_A1_fig1.jpg);
   background-position: 0% 0%;
}

.pointer {
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   background-color: red;
   position: absolute;
   width: 10px;
   height: 10px;
   background-size: contain;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways you can do this, I've seen some people use `::before` and `::after` pseudos, or the `background-attachment` property (works with `<img>` tags, not backgrounds).

I've opted and gone for absolute positioning the entire div. So we have an absolute positioned div, and a relative positioned parent. We set the height and width for each, plus the background image using `background-size`. Set overflow to hidden on the overlay. Then just use `top right bottom left` to position the div holding the image.

I also set you up with a centering method for your red dot that takes the size of the dot into account.

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9sp2te4o/1/

HTML

```
<html>
  <body>
    
    <div class="divOverlay">
      <div class="div-overlay-content" ></div>
       <div class="pointer" ></div>
    </div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.divOverlay {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow:hidden;  /* Full hidden */
  position:relative;  /* Set relative so absolute children are contained */
  background-color:rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  margin:10px;
}

.div-overlay-content{
  position:absolute; /* Absolute the div for positoning */
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size:cover; /* Cover entire div */
  left: -25%; /* position the div instead of the image */
  top: -25%; /* position the div instead of the image */
  
  background-image: url(https://topdrawer.aamt.edu.au/var/aamt/storage/images/media/tdt/patterns/p_gt_t3_e1_a1_fig1/278788-1-eng-AU/P_GT_T3_E1_A1_fig1.jpg);
}

.pointer {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);  /* Position while taking dimensions of div into account */
  height:10px;
  width:10px;
  background-color:red;
    
}
```

Comment: You are using background-size:cover;  which is not what i want .I dont want to resize the image to fit the div

Comment: Then don't use the cover  just make the div large enough to hold the full image

Comment: if i remove that property and set left and top to 0%, then the tope-left corner of the image is aligned with the top-left corner of the div. What i want is to align with the center of the div